# How to solve Firebase 403 PERMISSION_DENIED error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to use firebase on react, but I'm getting the 403 permission denied error
hear is my firebase.js firebase configuration

```js
import "firebase/compat/auth"
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app)
export const db = getFirestore(app)
export default app
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error that you are get?

Comment: it's already fixed out, answer below helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[in your console change this to true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHYFO.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).